# HTMLTestRunner parallel execution

Tags: python, html, unit-testing, parallel-processing

I'm using [HTMLTestRunner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/HTMLTestRunner/0.8.0) for my unit tests in order to generate a nice output report. Here's a snippet from my code:

```
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

suite = unittest.TestSuite()
...
report = open('Report.html', 'w')
result = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=report, verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

I'd like to parallelise the execution, and I can see a few extensions that provide this including testtools, nose and pytest. However, I can't see any way to integrate them with the current setup.

Does anyone know if and how they can be used so that I can still maintain the HTML output?